# Magento 2 : Make custom grid table appear only data that have been filtered

Tags: magento2, grid, filter, backorder

I have a custom module created to show list of backorder product, the list appear like this

[image]

as you can see on the grid table above under the column payment status there is 2 type of status which is

- payment_receive
- pending_payment

[image]

I don't want the list to appear all payment_status list, instead I want it to appear only payment_receive, means the query that call the list for this table if dumped in sql will be like

SELECT * FROM gshop_backorders WHERE payment_status = 'payment_receive';

then I want to hide the **payment_status** column

I have check for many ways such as adding getData function inside the DataProvider.php but unable to figure out how to do this, below is the code at `app/code/GShop/Order/Model/Gshopbackorders/DataProvider.php`

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace GShop\Order\Model\Gshopbackorders;

use GShop\Order\Model\ResourceModel\GshopBackorders\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;

class DataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected $collection;

    /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    protected $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loadedData;

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $model) {
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
        }
        $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('gshop_backorders');
        
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
            $model->setData($data);
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('gshop_backorders');
        }
        
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

and the ui component

app/code/GShop/Order/view/adminhtml/ui_component/gshop_order_gshop_backorders_listing.xml

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">gshop_order_gshop_backorders_listing.gshop_order_gshop_backorders_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <spinner>gshop_order_gshop_backorders_columns</spinner>
        <deps>
            <dep>gshop_order_gshop_backorders_listing.gshop_order_gshop_backorders_listing_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="gshop_order_gshop_backorders_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
        <settings>
            <storageConfig>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">backorders_id</param>
            </storageConfig>
            <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
        </settings>
        <aclResource>GShop_Order::gshop_backorders</aclResource>
        <dataProvider name="gshop_order_gshop_backorders_listing_data_source" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>backorders_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <action name="download">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">download</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Download</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="gshop_order/export/massdownload"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action name="placeorder">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">placeorder</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Place Order</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="gshop_order/placeorder/index"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </massaction>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <settings>
            <sticky>true</sticky>
        </settings>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters"/>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="gshop_order_gshop_backorders_columns">
        <settings>
            <editorConfig>
                <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">gshop_order_gshop_backorders_listing.gshop_order_gshop_backorders_listing.gshop_order_gshop_backorders_columns.ids</param>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">backorders_id</param>
                <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="gshop_order/gshopbackorders/inlineEdit"/>
                    <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </param>
            </editorConfig>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">gshop_order_gshop_backorders_listing.gshop_order_gshop_backorders_listing.gshop_order_gshop_backorders_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>

        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <settings>
                <indexField>backorders_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="backorders_id">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
                <label translate="true">ID</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="backorders_id">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">ID</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="product_name">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Product Name</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="sku">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">SKU</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="order_entity_id">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Order Entity Id</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="pre_order_number">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Pre Order Number</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="gtrust_orderno">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Gtrust Order Number</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="payment_method">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Payment Method</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="payment_status">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Payment Status</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="payment_transaction_id">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Payment Transaction Id</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="customer_id">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Customer Id</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="customer_email">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Customer Email</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="qty">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Qty</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Created At</label>
            </settings>
        </column> 
        <column name="order_datetime">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Order Date Time</label>
            </settings>
        </column> 
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="GShop\Order\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\GshopbackordersActions">
            <settings>
                <indexField>backorders_id</indexField>
                <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled>
                <resizeDefaultWidth>107</resizeDefaultWidth>
            </settings>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Appreciate someone that can help explain what is the ways to add in this filter so that only payment_status = 'payment_receive' data appear in the list

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to find out solution to this problem after a lots of try and error and dumping data to understand

Basically just need to add this code into the __construct function of the DataProvider

```
$filter = $this->filterBuilder
->setConditionType('like')
->setField('payment_status')
->setValue('%payment_receive%')
->create();

$this->addFilter($filter);
```

thus the finalized code for `app/code/GShop/Order/Model/Gshopbackorders/DataProvider.php` is as below

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace GShop\Order\Model\Gshopbackorders;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\ReportingInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;

class BackorderDataProvider extends DataProvider
{

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        ReportingInterface $reporting,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        RequestInterface $request,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $reporting, $searchCriteriaBuilder, $request, $filterBuilder, $meta, $data);
        
        $filter = $this->filterBuilder
        ->setConditionType('like')
        ->setField('payment_status')
        ->setValue('%payment_receive%')
        ->create();

        $this->addFilter($filter);
    }

}
```